# Orchard custom token to store title

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have myself a custom Orchard Token like so

```
public void Describe(DescribeContext context) 
        {
            context.For("Site", T("Site"), T("Site settings."))
                .Token("RootUrl", T("RootUrl"), T("The current site's root url."));

            context.For("Topic", T("Topic"), T("Topic contents."))
                .Token("Title", T("Title"), T("Title of the topic"));
        }

        public void Evaluate(EvaluateContext context)
        {
            context.For("Site", _orchardServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Request)
                .Token("RootUrl", token => _orchardServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));

            context.For<IContent>("Topic")
                .Token("Title", content =>
                {
                    int id = content.As<CommentPart>().Record.CommentedOn;
                    var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id);
                    return contentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title;
                })
                .Chain("Title", "Title", content => 
                {
                    int id = content.As<CommentPart>().Record.CommentedOn;
                    var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id);
                    return contentItem.As<TitlePart>().Title;
                });
        }
```

In my Orchard CMS I have a rule that sends out an email when a comment is added so in the text box of that email I have typed in

```
{Topic.Title}
```

However this is never populated, can anyone bring some light to this dark corner of mine?

Answer (score 0):

What's missing here is context. The code evaluating the tokenized string will provide a context object that will be what the tokens are evaluated against. Typically, there will be a Content object on that context, which is what will be passed into the Content token's Lambda. Here, you're telling the system that if it finds something called "Topic" of type IContent on the context, it should be handled by your logic. Unfortunately, that never happens because such an object is not set onto the context by the calling code.

From your question, it seems like your intention is to get the title of a comment when one is added. You could, I think, just do `Content.DisplayText`, but if you must develop your own token, attach it to the content token rather than build a new root one that will not get evaluated where you intend. So that would be a Topic token off of Content.